# Variable number of object parameters to JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

I want to pass in a variable number of javascript functions.

Doing it like this:

```
function() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);  
    for(var i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
        console.log(args[i]);
    }
}
```

But, I want to pass in a variable number of array or keyvalue items something like:

```
dsmetrics.track({'object':'hi', 'type:1}, {'object':'hi', 'type:1}, {'object':'hi', 'type:1});
```

But that is the wrong syntax. Is there a correct syntax which can handle that?

Comment: @user: Why do you think the syntax is wrong? Are you getting an Error? In your example, each `type` property is missing its closing quotation mark. That would cause an error if you're actually running this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you think that is the wrong syntax.

If you want it to be more dynamic, where you'll have a variable number of arguments in an array, that you want to pass as individual arguments, you can use `.apply()`.

```
var args = [{'object':'hi', 'type':1}, {'object':'hi', 'type':1}, {'object':'hi', 'type':1}];

dsmetrics.track.apply( dsmetrics, args );
```

*(Fixed unbalanced quotation marks from the question.)*

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = {
  "param1" : "value1",
  "param2" : "value2",
  "param3" : {
    "param4" : "value4",
    "param5" : "value5"
  },
  "param6" : "value6"
};

function func(obj) {

}
```

Comment: Can this be done in the method class without declaring obj? Can we simply do new {'param':'param'}

Comment: you can call a function that way like `func({'param':'param'})`

Answer (score 1):

[See live example](http://jsfiddle.net/es6CP/). You can do this exactly the way you have it, it is creating an argument for each object. There is nothing wrong with the syntax.

```
function objArgs() {
    for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++){
        console.log(arguments[i]);
    }
}

objArgs({one: 1}, {two: 2}, {three: 3});
```

It really just depends on your business application. If it makes more sense to pass these arguments separately, or combine them into a single array.

Comment: The `slice()` in the question isn't actually wrong. It is a way of converting an Arguments object to an Array, which is sometimes necessary.

Comment: You are right, I tried it and it didn't change, is the slice better?

Comment: Depends on the needs. If for example you need to act on the arguments as though it was an Array, then you need to convert it first. If you're just iterating over the arguments, then probably not. Not sure if there's a performance hit for iterating the arguments directly.

Comment: Right because you can iterate an object or an array, so converting it to an array could potentially be safer. Thanks for the info :)